# Bottom toolbar not appears

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

i'um using a top toolbar and bootom toolbar into a panel like this:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: 'pnlLogin',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'left'
    },
    items:[
           {
               xtype: 'textfield',
               flex: 1,
               id: 'ioUser',
               label: 'User'
           },
           {
               xtype: 'textfield',
               flex: 1,
               id: 'ioPwd',
                       inputType: 'password',
               label: 'Password'
           }
    ],
    dockedItems: [
        {
            dock : 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Restricted Area'
        },
        {
            dock : 'bottom',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui: 'light',
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Login',
                    ui: 'confirm-round',
                    handler: function(b,e){
                        btnLoginClick();
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

the problem is BOTTOM TOOLBAR not appears!!
it appears only after i move my tablet!!

how can i solve it?
i need that it appears after panel render!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where is btnLoginClick(); method ?
if the file which cantent this method is load after this panel then this problem may happens...